# .NET Core Web API optional query parameter is still not null

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

There is many similar questions on StackOverflow then mine, but no one says about my issue.

I have REST API controller with following method:

```
    [HttpGet("Lists")]
    public Codebook GetFilterLists([FromQuery] FilterQuery? filterQuery = null)
    {
        // some select and return code
    }
```

All properties of `FilterQuery` class are display as optional on Swagger UI.
When I leave all of them empty and click on "Execute" button, Swagger UI makes this GET query:
`https://localhost:7137/api/PublicWeb/Lists`

Even so, the `filterQuery` parameter has value - instance of `filterQuery` with default values.
[image]

I tried change `JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition` settings in Program.cs, but it has no effect for this.

Do you have any idea, what I have wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the begining I want to share,  you may know [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and [optinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) are completely different concept. If you declare a parameter with int? marks it as nullable, but it is not optional: You must pass either a non-null integral value or null. Adding = null, however, is the syntax required for declaring the default value of an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments). You could [check more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-variable-annotations)

> .NET Core Web API optional query parameter is still not null. Do you have any idea, what I have wrong?

The behavior you are getting is expected becuase the property is set to null or a default value if its simple type but yours one is complex type thus, the value setting not null.

In addition to this, Non-nullable value types are set to default(T). Means it creates an instance but yours one are nullable and breaks the convension and consequently it will not find any source property matching with it that results in not null.

**Note:** You could [found more details here in the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#no-source-for-a-model-property).

> I tried change JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition settings
> in Program.cs, but it has no effect for this.

No, JsonSerializerOptions cannot resolve your issue. You would require [Custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample) to implement what you are execting. Here I am provideing you a sample illustration, but you have to improve it based on your requirement.

Custom Model Binder:

```cs
public class NullEntityBinder : IModelBinder
    {
       
        public NullEntityBinder()
        {
         
        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

             var model = new FilterQuery();



            if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("AreaOfAdjustmentId").FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                model.AreaOfAdjustmentId = Convert.ToUInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("AreaOfAdjustmentId").FirstOrDefault());
            }

            if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("DocumentName").FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                model.DocumentName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("DocumentName").FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (model.AreaOfAdjustmentId == null && model.DocumentName == null)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Wrap Your Model With Binder:

```cs
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(NullEntityBinder))]
public class FilterQuery
{
   
    public uint? AreaOfAdjustmentId { get; set; }
    public string? DocumentName { get; set; }
   
}
```

**Note:** In my test I have used two property as for demonstration, you would need to implement logic based on your other property as well.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#no-source-for-a-model-property)

Comment: Thank you very much @Md Farid Uddin Kiron for your rich answer and posted example. I will try implement it on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know how model binding works, this would not be possible right now; it will always try to populate the class with default values.

I think the recommended way, from how they have setup routing and binding, would be to have two different routes that handles the two scenarios: one if you are trying to give it a filterquery, and one with if you are not. Or just check the values inside of the filterquery object to see if it is valid or just the default values.